# Documentation tutorial: Why is my JFormFieldList showing a textbox?

Tags: component, mvc, form-fields-types

I was going through this part of the tutorial:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Using_the_database
Except I tried using my own names instead of 'helloworld'.

---

Everything else works fine, even the site-page loads the text from the
database. The problem is:

*On the backend 'Menu Item' options, where there's
supposed to be a list, it's just showing a blank textbox.*

[image]

---

**The codes I've used are:**

`site/views/uploadwizard/tmpl/default.xml`:

```
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_OMITTED_UPLOADWIZARD_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
        <message>COM_OMITTED_UPLOADWIZARD_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC</message>
    </layout>

    <fields
        name="request"
        addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_omitted/models/fields"
        >
        <fieldset name="request">
            <field
                name="id"
                type="ulwiz_wmode"
                label="COM_OMITTED_UPLOADWIZARD_FIELD_WMODE_LABEL"
                description="COM_OMITTED_UPLOADWIZARD_FIELD_WMODE_DESC"
                />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</metadata>
```

`admin/models/fields/ulwiz_wmode.php`:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldUlWiz_WMode extends JFormFieldList
{
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        $db    = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('id,wmode');
        $query->from('#__omitted_ulwiz_wmode');
        $db->setQuery((string) $query);
        $messages = $db->loadObjectList();
        $options  = array();

        if ($messages)
        {
            foreach ($messages as $message)
            {
                $options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', $message->id, $message->wmode);
            }
        }

        $options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);

        return $options;
    }
}
```

And the Database description:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__omitted_ulwiz_wmode`;

CREATE TABLE `#__omitted_ulwiz_wmode` (
    `id`        INT(11)     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `wmode`     VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `published` tinyint(4)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

    ENGINE =MyISAM
    AUTO_INCREMENT =0
    DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8;

INSERT INTO `#__omitted_ulwiz_wmode` (`wmode`) VALUES
('Option1Text'),
('Option2Text');
```

---

How do I fix this?
I've been at it for hours and am unable to move over to the next part of the tutorial hence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it is not able to get the field. I see filename you have defined as `ulwiz_wmode.php` and in class name you are using this `JFormFieldUlWiz_WMode`. Make sure the naming convention is very proper and should be same as class name and filename. It should be `JFormFieldUlwiz_wmode`.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldUlwiz_wmode extends JFormFieldList
{
   protected $type = 'ulwiz_wmode'; //also add this line

   protected function getOptions()
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

You are creating your own custom field. For more details on custom fields refer this documentation:

> https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Comment: Apologies. `$type='ulwiz_wmode'` is there in the actual code, forgot to copy it to here. I thought the $type automatically hooked the class to the right field type. So, I read up on the documentation in the link and wow, I didn't know the naming conventions were this strict. Also googling 'Camel Casing' gave a few hits where devs were asked to choose either `CamelCasing` or `under_score` naming conventions.

Comment: Finally tried out the coding: `Ulwiz_wmode` didn't work. But `UlwizWmode` and even `UlWizWMode` worked. I guess underscores aren't allowed here. I'm going to mark this as Answer since naming was indeed the issue. Thanks for the help! Funny though, I used `OmittedTableUlWiz_WMode` as the JTable class and that works, somehow.

Comment: I am glad it helped. :)